Attempt to find an easy description of the coproduct in the category of topological (abelian) groups
For consider a family of topological abelian groups $\{G_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in J}$ for some index set $J$. I sought for an easy description of the topology that the direct sum $G = \bigoplus_{\alpha \in J} G_\alpha$ carries. Here's my attempt.
Note that each coset $xG_\alpha \subset G$ can be topologized by copying the topology of $G_\alpha$. This is well-defined over choices of $x$ because the topology carried by $G_\alpha$ is translation-invariant.
Let $\mathcal{T}$ the final topology over $G$ induced by all inclusion maps $i_{\alpha, x} : xG_\alpha \to G$. That is, a subset $U \subset G$ shall be open if and only if its inverse image $i_{\alpha, x}^{-1}[U]$ is open in $xG_\alpha$ for each $\alpha \in J$ and $x \in G$.
Let me prove that, under this topology, the group operations (binary operation and inversion) are continuous. It suffices to prove that $f : G \times G \to G$ defined by $f(x,y) = x^{-1} y$ is continuous. Since $\mathcal{T}$ is translation-invariant, it also suffices to prove that $f$ is continuous at $(e,e)$. Let $V \subset G$ be an open neighborhood of $e \in G$. Let $U_\alpha$ denote $i_{\alpha,e}^{-1}[V]$. Then $U_\alpha \subset G_\alpha$ is an open neighborhood of $e \in G_\alpha$. Since $G_\alpha$ is a topological group, it's possible to pick a neighborhood $U_\alpha'$ of $e \in G_\alpha$ such that, for every $x,y \in U_\alpha'$, $x^{-1} y \in U_\alpha$ holds.
Now consider the set $U = \bigcup_{1, 2, \cdots, n \in J} \{i_{1, e}(x_1) i_{2, e}(x_2) \cdots i_{n, e}(x_n) : x_1 \in U_1, x_2 \in U_2, \cdots, x_n \in U_n\}$. Then $U$ is an open neighborhood of $e \in G$ such that $f[U \times U] \subset V$, and the proof is complete.
It should be easy to check the universal property, but how can I modify this proof for general (might-be non-abelian) topological groups and free products? I guess, instead of $xG_\alpha$, I'd need $xG_\alpha y$, and in the last step, the indices $1, 2, \cdots, n \in J$ would need not be pairwise different.

The free product of topological groups sounds horrendous; do you actually need it for anything? I've never seen anyone try to define or use it.

Not sure what counts as an easy description for what is inherently an horrible construction, but have you already seen the first answer here?
